# AD groups of user in context of azure ad enterprise application

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Using graph api I want to fetch the list of ad group memberships related to user in context of specific enterprise application.

Example user sample@example.com in part of 20 AD groups and access to enterprise application is via ad group. I want to fetch the list of ad group which has given him access to specific enterprise application

I have read graph api docs. I did find the api to fetch all user groups memberships, separate one to fetch all ad groups allowed for enterprise application. Intersection of both api response helps to get my goal but want to understand if there is way to do the same using single graph api call.